# JSP not Evaluating with Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to render JSP in a Spring 3.2 using annotation driven configuration, but the JSP renders as a string and is not evaluated.

I am using the maven jetty plugin to run the webapp in development. So it seems as if everything should "just work".

The dependencies I am including to use JSP are

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The bean to configure JSP is

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

The controller is pretty straight forward

```
@Controller
public class RootController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
  public String login() {
    return "login";
  }
```

and the JSP is also pretty easy

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<%= "Hello World" %>
${ "Hello World" }
<form name="auth" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">
  <label>Username: <input type="text" name="j_username"></label>
  <label>Password: <input type="password" name="j_password"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the image the JSP is not being evaluated.  Is there anything I need to do to tell JSP to be evaluated when rendered.

[image: rendered page]

#### Edit 1

So just for a little extra information I used the [Resthub archetype resthub-mongodb-backbonejs-archetype](https://github.com/resthub/resthub.org/blob/master/spring-stack.rst#bootstrap-your-project) to bootstrap this project, which uses a WebAppInitializer rather than the older web.xml, and it uses new annotation driven beans rather than the xml beans.

---

#### EDIT 2

I have been smashing my head on this for all to long so I put the project on github https://github.com/austinbv/calendar/. Since I do not know what is important and what is not.

Thanks for the help

---

Comment: did you copy jstl.jar and standard.jar to WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: in my WEB-INF I do have the jstl library.  It is included by adding JSTL to my pom and at build time added

Comment: Did you try using `@EnableWebMvc` to your WebAppConfiguration class?

Comment: can you post your web.xml?

Comment: do you have login.jsp in View folder?

Answer (score 1):

@austinbv Please use the [SPRING LINK](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part2.html#step2.1) to check the setup. (As @Rohit has pointed you above - the missing piece)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using spring boot. Adding these dependencies to the project pom.xml resolved the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above given issue fixed for me after making following change in the "web.xml"

The spring servlet needs to be the default servlet. ie mapped to / and not /*.

Ref link: https://code-examples.net/en/q/b49ce1

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the appropriate view class

```
 public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
return resolver;
```

}

Comment: I get the same results after setting the ViewClass

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much actual will be my answer, but I had exactly the same issue (Spring + boot + maven + tomcat).
I solved it by removing the scope-provided from tomcat.embed dependence.  So, my dependence now looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, glad I tried it even though -1.

Answer (score 0):

Because JSP does not obey MVC pattern :P